# casting object to String[] object..?

Tags: java

Assume the following scenario.
i call a method like this

```
String[] arr = {"1","2","3"};
method(arr);
```

and the method signature is

```
public void method(Object o)
{
// how will i get back the String[] arr object now.. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing

```
public void method(Object o) {
   String[] arr = (String[]) o;
}
```

this means the only valid parameter type is String[] and you are better off making this clear with

```
public void method(String[] arr) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The casting would look like this:

```
final String[] array = (String[]) o;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it back.

```
String[] o2 = (String[]) o;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void method(Object o) {
   String[] arr = (String[]) o;
}
```

Here `o` is your passed `String[]` object. Just cast it to `String[]`. And if you are planning to pass an array every time then change your method signature to:

```
public void method(Object[] o)
```